# Get return value from process

Tags: c#, process

Hi I am trying to do the following:
I have a process which can take parameters (digits)
and return the sum of these numbers

```
Process P = Process.Start(sPhysicalFilePath, Param);
                int result = P.ExitCode;
```

I get the return value from "ExitCode"
the problem is:
the program sometimes finishes his work before the process 
so when the program reaches this line

```
int result = P.ExitCode;
```

I got an exception ..
my question is how to wait this process until it finishes its work
sorry I forget to say that's I am working with C# language

Answer (score 123, accepted):

use:

```
Process P = Process.Start(sPhysicalFilePath, Param);
P.WaitForExit();
int result = P.ExitCode;
```

from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit.aspx)

Answer (score -1):

You can try the below code:

```
    Dim P As New Process
    P = Process.Start(info)
    P.WaitForExit()
    fichiersATraiter = P.ExitCode
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: OP asked for C# not VB ;)
So you should put a disclaimer saying not C#

Comment: In this example, 'fichiersATraiter ' wont work.

Comment: I don't know which was the greater waste of time: me seeing VBA code in the year 2021 or me googling a bit because I wanted to know more about this traitor Fichier. Both distractions yielded no benefit.