# Shared values between child and parent processes

Tags: c#, process, parent-child, handle, child-process

I am executing a process like this:

```
Process process = new Process();
process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(localpath);
process.Exited += new EventHandler(process_Exited);
process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
process.Start();
```

where localpath is the path to the .docx file. I also have a Word Add-In and I have an `Import` button in the ribbon. Once pressed it should set some value let's say "hi" and, once exited, the process_Exited() method should be able to:

```
MessageBox.Show(the mysterious accessor for that "hi");
```

However, I do not know if that is possible at all since I have found many people telling how I cannot access the parent form if it is in another process. So I gave up on that idea and all I want to do is to sent that "hi" to the parent form (which is in different application), which would be an indicator enough as of what to do next.

I tried using this project, but my messagebox appears in the same window, not in parent, because these are two separate applications (WORD and my application). I also tried sending Environment value around, but I can only get it in child (and not set!).

So, is there a way to get some value to be passed from child to parent process?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are many ways to pass information from child to parent.

If your child process is a console application, you can have the child write the value on the console (i.e. `Console.WriteLine`). The parent process can redirect the child's output and read it. See [Capturing console output from a .NET application (C#)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/186822/56778) for an example.

If you have a small set of possible values to be returned (i.e. "hi", "goodbye", "help", etc.), then you can enumerate them and have the child return an exit code from 0 to N, where N is the number of possible values. See [Get return value from process](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1585354/56778) for an example of getting the process exit code. To set the child process exit code, either set [Environment.ExitCode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.environment.exitcode.aspx), or return the value from `Main`.

If you can't use the console and you want to return text data, you can use [Named Pipes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085.aspx) for interprocess communication. The parent program creates the pipe and calls the child. The child opens the pipe and sends data base to the parent before exiting.

There are other possibilities, but I suspect one of those will do what you want.

Comment: Yes, my child process is application of MS WORD, so the named pipes that is. Thanks!

Comment: @jimmischel, your solution not working in program is running. It only for program start with parameter.

Comment: @VănLộc: I mentioned many possible "solutions" in this answer. Which one is not working for you?

Comment: @JimMischel: First link mentions using `StartInfo.Arguments` only send when an initial application. Other solutions do not relate to my problem.

Comment: @VănLộc: The OP's question was specifically for that situation: when one program starts another, and wants to get some data from it. That's the question I answered. It's no surprise that my solution to that problem doesn't solve the problem of how to communicate with a program that's already running.