# Sending an instance of an object's memory as a parameter

Tags: c#, wpf

I have another program executable which I have added as a reference in my C# file. Right now I'm currently transitioning to that program by using it's namespace followed by the first class to instantiate a object, then I am simply just showing that instance, i.e:

```
// Instantiate next screen using the namespace and accessing the first class
myProg.MainWindow myProgInst = new myProg.MainWindow();

// Call myProg
myProgInst.ShowDialog();
```

My question is, instead of opening a new window - is there a way I can actually *send* the instance of memory from `myProg` to the program calling it so that the elements of the object will just transition to the window of the program calling it? Essentially I am trying to eliminate the opening of a new window if I can just throw the other programs information into the one calling it. Maybe you can't do this, just thought I'd ask.

Thanks in advance

Comment: please, show code where you send data to another program.

Comment: *"send the instance of memory from myProg to the program calling it so that the elements of the object will just transition to the window of the program calling it"* - are you talking about inter-process communications (IPC) ? Or a simple command-line parameters (arguments)?

Comment: @StepUp I'm asking how to do that. Sinatr, It may be a form of that, though I am not familiar what that is.

Comment: You can [return result](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1585354/1997232) from another process (or result, if its more than a simple `int`, can be passed via file, which name in turn is passed as command-line parameter to `myProg`). See more about [IPC](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365574(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Interesting, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

you can use "ref" to send object by reference in c#. create a method like this in other program and call this from myProg class.

```
//example
void Test (ref ClassName myProg)
{

}
```

This function will not create a new object of the class instead it will pass the same object by reference.

I hope this is what you are asking for.

Comment: Can you give an example

Answer (score 0):

You could make a `TCP` connection between them, both need a `TCPlistener` and a `TCP` client. [Here you can see a tutorial.](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1415/Introduction-to-TCP-client-server-in-C)

Also, you can use Named Pipes for Network Interprocess Communication [See this tutorial.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546085.aspx)